# Replace Add to Cart button ONLY if Cart is not empty

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I want to remove the Add to Cart button from the single-product-page and then replace it with a "Go to cart" custom button if the cart is not empty (since folks should only be able to buy the item once). If the cart is empty, then Add to Cart should be there.

This is what I have, which in theory SHOULD do the trick, but it won't:

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_variation','view_cart_store');

function view_cart_store() {
    if ( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ) {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart' );
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_variation', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
    echo '<a class="button wc-forward" href="'.wc_get_page_permalink( 'cart' ).'">'. __( 'Back to cart', 'woocommerce' ) .'</a>';
    } else {
        //do nothing
    }
}
```

It's not doing it. After some testing, I think that the code to remove the action from `woocommerce_single_variation` prevents the div from being rendered, which will then not include my button.

Any idea on how to implement this?